# AngularJSで 要素からscopeを得る逆のことをしたいです。

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[DOM要素からAngularJSのスコープのオブジェクトを得る術 | きたけーの朝は早いブログ](http://kitak.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/11/12/233109)
では、要素から、scopeを得ているのですが、これの逆で、scopeからそのscopeの要素を取得するといった事がしたいです。

ご教示お願い致します

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$element`はいかがでしょう？
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
    <button ng-click="go()">click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>

function SampleCtrl($scope, $element) {
  $scope.go = function() {
      console.log($element);
  };
}
```

scopeの概念として、1点気をつけて頂きたいのは$elementで取得するのは、この場合div要素です。
ちょっと試していませんが。おそらくng-repeatが絡む場合は、ng-repeat部分になったと思います。

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました・・


````
$("[ng-controller]").filter(function () {return angular.element(this).scope() == $scope });
````